# Dynamic query with INNER JOINs in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which uses a inner join with table t1 which has two columns `ID` and `FID`, in the stored procedure there are two variables `@ID` and `@FID`, Inner join as

```
 Inner Join t1 on t1.ID = @ID and t1.FID = @FID
```

Now the problem is that I want to make it dynamic. If the `FID` from table t1 is null then I should apply only the ID matching part as

```
Inner Join t1 on t1.ID = @ID
```

Otherwise It should be the original

```
Inner Join t1 on t1.ID = @ID and t1.FID = @FID
```

Comment: Not a SQL guru but would a simple change to `(t1.FID = @FID OR t1.FID IS NULL)` work?

Comment: Listen to Mike. The structure of the JOIN is just like a WHERE clause. You can do all sorts of things there.

Answer (score 0):

The above part should be re-written like this:

```
Inner Join t1 on t1.ID = @ID and ISNULL(t1.FID,@FID) = @FID
```

Notice that I am assuming that @FID is not nullable field.